# Does't working in MKDirections to get iOS 7 Map Directions and Routes in two points?

Tags: dictionary, ios7, directions, xcode5.0.1

I have tried the map directions in iOS 7 sample codes in following link[iOS 7 Map Directions and Routes](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_MKDirections_to_get_iOS_7_Map_Directions_and_Routes) It's working only in US based latitude and longitude .I have tried indian based latitude and longitude it's not working .response came to direction not available.any one help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late but if someone is looking for it: MKDirections is not available in all countries.

Here is a list with the countries where it should work: http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions